# How to increment a specific column based on the value in another column in the same table

Tags: sql, triggers, sql-server-2014

I have a table that I will be using for a tally. Within that table I have the following columns: T_ID, L_ID,L1,L2,L3,L4,L5. L_ID is of the data type INT. The value in L_ID can go up to 5. I want to create a trigger that checks the value in L_ID, depending on that value whether it be from 1 to 5. It will increment the corresponding column L1,L2,L3,L4,L5, these values are automatically zero.
For example L_ID=3 therefore L3 will increment by one.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Also, what kind of trigger is that? Insert, update or what?

Comment: @brian tompsett i'm using sql server 2014 management studio and  its  an update trigger

Answer (score 0):

So, you could do it with case expressions and instead of insert/update triggers, an instead of insert for the original insert (assuming you wanted this behaviour on the original insert and not just all the Lx columns at 0:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[InsteadTrigger] ON [dbo].[original_table]
    INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
    INSERT  INTO original_table
            SELECT  L_ID ,
                    CASE WHEN L_ID = 1 THEN L1 + 1
                         ELSE L1
                    END ,
                    CASE WHEN L_ID = 2 THEN L2 + 1
                         ELSE L2
                    END ,
                    CASE WHEN L_ID = 3 THEN L3 + 1
                         ELSE L3
                    END ,
                    CASE WHEN L_ID = 4 THEN L4 + 1
                         ELSE L4
                    END ,
                    CASE WHEN L_ID = 5 THEN L5 + 1
                         ELSE L5
                    END
            FROM    INSERTED;
        GO
```

Then to get updates to work, you would need an instead of update trigger such as this one:

```
CREATE TRIGGER InsteadUpdTrigger ON original_table
    INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
    UPDATE  original_table
    SET     L_ID = i.L_ID ,
            L1 = CASE WHEN i.L_ID = 1 THEN i.L1 + 1
                      ELSE i.L1
                 END ,
            L2 = CASE WHEN i.L_ID = 2 THEN i.L2 + 1
                      ELSE i.L2
                 END ,
            L3 = CASE WHEN i.L_ID = 3 THEN i.L3 + 1
                      ELSE i.L3
                 END ,
            L4 = CASE WHEN i.L_ID = 4 THEN i.L4 + 1
                      ELSE i.L4
                 END ,
            L5 = CASE WHEN i.L_ID = 5 THEN i.L5 + 1
                      ELSE i.L5
                 END
    FROM    INSERTED i
    WHERE   original_table.T_ID = i.T_ID;
```

Just a note that I've assumed that T_ID here is the primary key, which is required in this circumstance to ensure that the update trigger only modifies the rows involved in the original update.